# hiera_hash/hiera_array in foreman?

Tags: puppet, foreman, hiera

Is there a way in foreman to have puppet variables appended from parent host groups?

Example of desired functionality:

```
AllHosts:
ssh_allow[10.1.1.0/32]

AllHosts/publicHosts:
ssh_allow[71.0.0.0/8]

A host in the publicHost groups would have:
ssh_allow[10.1.1.0/32, 71.0.0.0/8]
```